# Is it possible get a query result and use it as a java code?

Tags: java, android, sql

I am trying to build a class using SQLiteOpenHelper. I would like to get an execSQL sentence in dynamic form. For example, I want to record some java line codes in a SQL database and use them to execute those lines.

Example:
This is de correct form

```
db.execSQL("insert into "+tabla+" values ("+idname+",'"+name+"',owner '"+owner+"')");
```

And I would like use like this. The result of query would be

```
insert into "+tabla+" values ("+idname+",'"+name+"',owner '"+owner+"')
```

That result would be used like...

```
db.execSQL(query);
```

Comment: What is now your challenges?

Comment: please explain the issue better

Comment: Are you looking for rawQuery ??

[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.CancellationSignal)

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Put on variable like this

```
String myQuery = "insert into "+tabla+" values ("+idname+",'"+name+"',owner '"+owner+"')"
```

Use your variable `myQuery` where you want, as follow

```
db.execSQL(myQuery);
```